# Objective C. Regular expression to eliminate anything after 3 dots

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4

I wrote the following code to eliminate anything after 3 dots

```
currentItem.summary = @"I am just testing. I am ... the second part should be eliminated";
NSError * error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(.)*(/././.)(.)*" options:0  error:&error];

if(nil != regex){
    currentItem.summary = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:currentItem.summary
                               options:0  range:NSMakeRange(0, [currentItem.summary length])
                                               withTemplate:@"$1"];
}
```

However, my input and output are the same. The correct output should be "I am just testing. I am".

I was trying to do this using regular expression because I have a database of other regular expressions that I run on the string. I know the performance might not be as good as a plain text find or replace but the strings involved are short. I also tried using "\" to escape the dots in the regex, but I was getting a warning.

There is another question with a similar topic but the match strings are not for objective c.

Comment: As a few people have pointed out below, a regex is overkill for the given problem.  Read up on NSString's various methods for finding substrings.

Comment: Don't forget that there is a single three dot character … vs ... - so depending on where the string comes in you may need to look through both.

Comment: It also appears that the comment does not show the difference. On a mac - type 'option ;' to get the ellipsis.

Comment: Whenever you get an error or warning from non-working code, include it in the question. This not only makes the issue more understandable for answerers, it makes it easier for others experiencing a similar issue to search for this Q&A.

Answer (score 4):

This is much easier and will accomplish what you want:

```
NSRange range = [currentItem.summary rangeOfString:@"..."];
if (range != NSNotFound) {
    currentItem.summary = [currentItem.summary substringToIndex:range.location];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have forward slashes, `/`, instead of backward slashes, `\`, in your pattern. Also if you wish to match everything before the three dots you should use `(.*)` - tag everything matched by the enclosed `.*`. (The other parentheses in the pattern are redundant.)

Answer (score 2):

Nice alternative:

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:currentItem.summary];   
[scanner scanUpToString:@"..." intoString: &currentItem.summary];
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommended regex for your problem:

```
regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(.*)\\s*\\.{3}.*$"
```

Main differences between this one and yours:

- uses backslashes to escape special chars
- uses `^` and `$` to anchor at the beginning and end of the string
- only captures the interesting section with `()`
- strips whitespace before the `...` by ignoring any number of whitespace chars (`\s*`).

Answer (score 0):

After correcting the slashes and other improvements, my final expression is:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(.*)\\.{3}.*$" 
                                                                                options:0 
                                                                                error:&error];
```

Comment: SO uses a Q&A format, rather than a forum. It's fine to answer your own question, but the answer should be just an answer, not a response to other answers or comments, and shouldn't include any details about the question. The latter should be handled by editing the question. However, in this case, CRD and jimbojw's answers are close enough to your final solution that there's little need to post your own. Make sure you accept one of theirs.